# Will NodaTime work in a web application which has been hosted in a intranet environment without internet connection?

Tags: timezone, nodatime

I have a Web application which is hosted in an Intranet Environment without Internet connection. Will NodaTime work in the web application and will it be able to retreive the TimeZone information from the TZDB/ OLSON DB without internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a version of TZDB is built into the NodaTime assembly, and is accessible via [`DateTimeProviders.Tzdb`](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/api/html/P_NodaTime_DateTimeZoneProviders_Tzdb.htm). It's typically the version which was the latest at the time of the release build.

You can [supply a newer version too](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.1.x/docs/userguide/tzdb.html), should you wish to (still without a network connection at execution time, because you'd take this step separately).

What *doesn't* exist at the moment (and it sounds like you don't need) is using an internet connection to fetch the latest version and use it at execution time.